# timer plugin for a game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a jQuery plugin that can display a timer with miliseconds and also return that time to save a highscore. does anyone know a good one? It should also at least try to avoid cheating.

Thanks

Comment: no jquery is necessary for a timer.

Comment: If this will be realized only on js you won't be protected from cheating

Comment: It's very easy to create a timer yourself, probably easier than using a plugin, search for `setInterval`. And like the others said, since Javascript is run on the client-side it will never be secure (without using a server-side language alongside).

Answer (score 0):

I think that to make a tamper-proof timer, it is not enough to use a client-side JS plugin, you will have to check the time on the server. For example, send an AJAX request on start and on finish and measure the time between them.

As for the clock plugin, you can for example use [epiclock](http://code.google.com/p/epiclock/), but do not rely on it to measure the time.